# Problem for Neo4j loading .dump file correctly, but failed to show the database

Tags: neo4j

My Neo4j version is community-4.2.4 in the Mac OS.
I used 'bin/neo4j-admin load --from=xxx/g.db.dump --database=xxx.db --force'. And succeed in finding db file in /data/databases as photo showed below.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0kj5u.png)

But the result returned in Browser adding 'show databases' and cannot find the database what I want.
Thanks u guys all for helping me.
OR sending email for communicating more at **masichengyo@gamil.com**.

---

Answer (score 1):

So `neo4j-admin load` and `neo4j-admin restore` take care of setting up the db in the filesystem. Back in the 3.5.x days this was enough, provided the name of the graph directory matched the name of the active graph configured in the neo4j.conf.

In Neo4j 4.x we support multidatabase, and the system database is where we can do things such as creating new databases, and if you CREATE DATABASE in the system db with the name of the new database, it will use just use the files it finds and create the entry in the system db, allowing you to use it and switch to it in Neo4j.

Since you're on community edition, you won't be able to create a new database, you're restricted to only the `neo4j` database, so your import would have to force it using `neo4j` as the db name, and it would overwrite your current neo4j db.

If you need to create multiple databases besides neo4j and system, then you need to be using enterprise edition.

Comment: Firstly, thanks for helping me. I have delete the other database and remain the default one but I find that I can't login as usual lol. Then I have reinstalling neo4j for many times but no use. It says " Could not connect with the "neo4j://" scheme to this Neoj server. Automatic retry using the "bolt://" scheme in a moment...". Dude, can U helping me solving again? I'll be appreciate.

Comment: Check your debug logs for reasons why it might not be working. Also check to make sure all loaded files are owned by the user that will run neo4j (usually the `neo4j` user, that's at the OS level, not within Neo4j itself). Remember that since you have the dump available for loading, you could just blow away your instance completely and start all over, make sure you can connect to it, then shut down and perform the load operation.

Comment: Luckily, I had restore the original condition of Neo4. From the help of yours, Is it I should keeping my user in 'neo4j' and keeping using the default database 'neo4j' right? So what command should I enter for loading an 'g.db.dump' file into 'neo4j' database exactly in the terminal? I had better follow your advice. Thanks a lot ^-^.

Comment: BTW, the 'g.db.dump' file comes from others. I wanne check the relationship zzz.

Comment: You need to use `--database=neo4j` in there so the load overwrite the `neo4j` database with the backup. It will of course overwrite whatever you had in the `neo4j` database. The instance needs to be offline before you perform the load.

Comment: Based on your advice. I had try again. Yep, before loading I had stop the perform. Then I check the result in 'localhost:7474' but still got 'Could not connect with the "neo4j://" scheme to this Neoj server. Automatic retry using the "bolt://" scheme in a moment...'. Is it means I shouldn't overwrite the neo4j database or I choose the wrong way? Oh man, thank u so much.

Comment: Check your debug logs, they should provide some insight into what's going on.